# Failed to deploy application. Environment must have instance profile associated with it

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

All of a sudden (I don't remember any specific change that would have caused this). I'm not able to deploy my application to elastic beanstalk. I've tried manually uploading a zip file and I get the following errors:

[image: errors]

I see at the top it is prompting me to associate an instance profile, so I click on "click here":

[image: instance profile]

Then I click save to let it create the default profile for me, and it just spins for over 30 min.

[image: spinning]

I'm not sure what an Instance Profile is, I've never had to deal with it before, and [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) says it should be managed for me by aws.

Comment: I don't know if I should make an answer out of this, but in my situation, it wasn't too difficult to just clone the environment and update all the Route53 routes pointing to it. This resolved the issue.